# setting data types in MS ACCESS SQL Insert queries

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

How can we explicitly convert data types in INSERT INTO/SELECT queries in MS Access?

Sample Query:

```
INSERT INTO pStudents( pStudentID, pDate, pRate, pGrade )
SELECT sStudentID, sDate, sRate, sGrade
FROM sStudents
WHERE (((sStudents.sStudentID) Is Not Null);
```

Here I want to convert fields from sStudents table before inserting in pStudents to following:

```
pStudentID = text
pDate = Short Date
pRate = Double
pGrade = text
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post a sample query as wela as the datatypes that you want to convert to/from?

Comment: @bluefeet sample query with data types updated above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the built-in conversion functions of Access in the queries:

```
Select CStr(NumericColumn) from Table
```

...or as an `INSERT` query:

```
Insert Into AnotherTable (StringColumn)
Select CStr(NumericColumn) from Table
```

Did you mean something like that?

---

**EDIT:**

Okay, your sample query with conversions would look like this:

```
INSERT INTO pStudents( pStudentID, pDate, pRate, pGrade )
SELECT CStr(sStudentID), CDate(sDate), CDbl(sRate), CStr(sGrade)
FROM sStudents
WHERE (((sStudents.sStudentID) Is Not Null);
```

However, this will only work if the columns contain only data that can actually be converted into the given type.

For example, you can convert a `String` column to `Double` with `CDbl()` - but only if the selected rows contain only values that can actually be converted into `Double`.
As soon as you select one row with a value that contains something else than numeric values (like 'hello'), the conversion will fail.

On the other hand, do you **really** need the conversions?
Access can convert a lot by itself. For example, you can insert values from a numeric column into a string column, Access will convert it by itself. You don't have to use `CStr()` for that.

Comment: "As soon as you select one row with a value that contains something else than numeric values the conversion will fail" -- actually, the whole statement will fail. Also it will fail for nulls (note a null is not a value -- actually, in Access it might be: I have a truly marvellous proof of this, which this comment is too small to contain). Also note that the conversion functions are built into the SQL engine: a simple proof is try try using `CDEC()` (cast to `DECIMAL`): it takes a different number of arguments than its VBA equivalent and doesn't work! But good answer ;)

Comment: I know that the whole statement will fail...but I assumed that it's clear that the whole statement fails if one conversion in the statement fails :)

Comment: @onedaywhen I look forward to 2370 in that case.

Comment: @Remou: what is the significance of 2370?

Comment: @onedaywhen The expected delay for the proof. "This theorem was first conjectured by Pierre de Fermat in 1637, famously in the margin of a copy of Arithmetica where he claimed he had a proof that was too large to fit in the margin. No successful proof was published until 1995"

Comment: @onedaywhen oops :) :) <-- the two missing smilies.

Comment: @Remou: Doh! 2370 just looked too far in the future to be a significant date, should have engaged brain :)

Comment: @Remou: Sub S(): Dim c: Set c = CreateObject("ADOX.Catalog"): With c: .Create "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\D.mdb": With .ActiveConnection: Dim S: For Each S In Array("CREATE TABLE T1 (c1 INT NOT NULL, c2 INT, UNIQUE (c1, c2));", "CREATE TABLE T2 (c1 INTEGER NOT NULL, c2 INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (c1, c2) REFERENCES T1 (c1, c2) ON UPDATE CASCADE);", "INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (1, NULL);", "INSERT INTO T2 VALUES (1, NULL);", "UPDATE T1 SET c2 = 1;"): .Execute S: Next: Dim r: Set r = .Execute("SELECT * FROM T2 WHERE c2 IS NULL;"): MsgBox r.EOF: End With: End With: End Sub

Answer (score 3):

This should work. If you want Date, you can use CDate, however this will make sure the date is a short date (http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/format.php)

```
INSERT INTO pStudents( pStudentID, pDate, pRate, pGrade ) 
SELECT CStr(sStudentID), Format(sDate, "Short Date"), CDbl(sRate), CStr(sGrade) 
FROM sStudents WHERE (((sStudents.sStudentID) Is Not Null);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many conversion function that are available in Access.

```
CBool(expression)
CByte(expression)
CCur(expression)
CDate(expression)
CDbl(expression)
CDec(expression)
CInt(expression)
CLng(expression)
CSng(expression)
CStr(expression)
CVar(expression)
```

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/type-conversion-functions-HA001229018.aspx

Then you would use these functions in your `INSERT INTO/SELECT` query:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (field)...
SELECT Cstr(fieldValue)...
FROM table2
```

If you need to convert each of the fields in sStudents, then based on your edit you could do the following:

```
INSERT INTO pStudents( pStudentID, pDate, pRate, pGrade )
SELECT CStr(sStudentID), CDate(sDate), CDbl(sRate), CStr(sGrade)
FROM sStudents
WHERE (((sStudents.sStudentID) Is Not Null);
```